# PHP not echoing all the MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a comment box, in which

- Comment box will be under the post
- Every comment box has the same id as the post has
- That's why i preffered to do a while loop

Somehow i was successful in echoing the rows of the comments but, the problems is *the first row(yes the first one) is not being shown/echoed .

Here are my codes  : 
Note: there is another while loop in which this code is executed.

```
// making the comments box 
    $dbc->select_db("feed_update_comment");
     $select_comment_table = "SELECT * FROM feed_comment_" . $row['id'] . " ORDER BY id";
$result_query_select_comment_table = $dbc->query($select_comment_table);
if(!$result_query_select_comment_table) {
    $result_select_comment_table = array("full_name" => "", "comment"=> "No comments yet.");

}
else {
    $result_select_comment_table = $result_query_select_comment_table->fetch_assoc();
}
echo '<div id="feed_comment_box_' . $row['id'] . '"' . 'class="feed_comment_box_cl"><div id="add_comment_id" class="add_comment_cl">
<form class="comment_form" method="post" action="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  . '">
<input name="comment_full_name" type="text" class="input_comment_full_name">  </input> 
<textarea name="input_comment_text" type="text" class="input_comment_text" ></textarea><input class="submit_input" name="comment_submit" type="submit"></input> <br>
 </form>
</div><br>
<div class="comment_box_cl">';
while ($results_select_comment_table = $result_query_select_comment_table->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<table tabindex="0" class="comment_box"><tr> <td class="comment_text">' . $results_select_comment_table["comment"] . '</td></tr><br>' . 
'<tr> <td class="comment_full_name">' .  $results_select_comment_table["full_name"]. '</td></tr><br>'
. '</table>';
}
echo '</div></div>';    
echo '</div>';          

//making of comment box finishes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lines:

```
else {
$result_select_comment_table = $result_query_select_comment_table->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Comment: every time you do `fetch_assoc()`, you get the following row, and you weren't using the first fetch...